# RNN for parallel multivariate time series

Tags: r, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, stock

I have a dataset of several stocks, so how can I use R to form only one prediction model for the "whole dataset", not just 1 stock but for all stocks. I think it'd be "many to many" RNN but I have no idea if that’s right or not.

I did try to find RNN with multivariate timeseries but all I found is many models talking about many input and 1 output such as housing price as output and rental price, area, etc as input.

Meanwhile, my case is: stock 1, stock 2, stock 3, .... and the output is the prediction of stock 1, stock 2, stock 3 and I need to create ONLY ONE model (not abt 1 stock and 1 model).

Comment: Can't you just change the output of any model from having dimension `1` to having dimension `N`?

Comment: I figured out using darts would solve it all. Thank you any @cheersmate